# How to use pagination in BootstrapVue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I have created a b-table that stores all the data from the API that has been hit from Swagger UI, but since the data has a lot of characters in string, [image: current] My questions are how to make the data in each row be hovered on click to show the real data from API that hasn't been truncated? I've tried using v-b-tooltip but it seems doesn't work. If I may, I also wanted to know more about how to make the b-pagination works to load another data as I navigate page further.

Here's my current code:

```html
<template>
  <base-header>
    <template>
      <b-card body>
        <b-card-header class="border-0">
          <h3 class="mb-0">Stock List</h3>
        </b-card-header>
        <template>
          <div class="text-center">
            <b-table responsive dark striped hover:true :items="items" :fields="fields">
              <template #cell()="data">
                <span v-b-tooltip.hover :title="data.value">
                  {{ data.value }}
                </span>
              </template>
            </b-table>
          </div>
        </template>
        <div class="overflow-auto">
          <b-card-footer class="py-4 d-flex justify-content-end">
            <b-pagination
              v-model="currentPage"
              :total-rows="rows"
              :per-page="perPage"
              aria-controls="my-table"
            ></b-pagination>
          </b-card-footer>
        </div>
      </b-card>
    </template>
  </base-header>
</template>
```

and then here's the script

```js
<script>
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import { getAllProvinces } from '~/api/delivery'
export default {
  // components: {
  // },
  data() {
    return {
      perPage: 10,
      currentPage: 1,
      allStock: 0,
      text: '',
      rows: 100,
      // ubah rows dan perPage biar paginationnya ada value
      items: [],

      fields: [
        {
          key: 'id',
          sortable: true,
          label: 'ID',
          class: 'truncate',
        },
        {
          key: 'requestId',
          sortable: true,
          label: 'Request ID',
          class: 'truncate',
        },
        {
          key: 'storeCode',
          sortable: true,
          label: 'Store Code',
          class: 'truncate',
        },
        {
          key: 'branchCode',
          sortable: true,
          label: 'Branch Code',
          class: 'truncate',
        },
        {
          key: 'b2bId',
          sortable: true,
          label: 'B2B ID',
          class: 'truncate',
        },
        {
          key: 'request',
          sortable: true,
          label: 'Request',
          class: 'truncate',
        },
        {
          key: 'response',
          sortable: true,
          label: 'Response',
          class: 'truncate',
        },
        {
          key: 'createDate',
          sortable: true,
          label: 'Create Date',
          class: 'truncate',
        },
        {
          key: 'errorClassification',
          sortable: true,
          label: 'Error Classification',
          class: 'truncate',
        },
      ],
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getAllStock()
  },
  methods: {
    getAllStock() {
      this.$axios
        .get(
          'API Link'
        )
        .then((res) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.log(res.data)
          this.items = res.data.stocks
          this.allStock = res.data
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          // console.log('cek res stock:', JSON.stringify(res.data))
        })
    },
    computed: {
      rows() {
        return this.items.length
      },
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

```css
<style>
.truncate {
  max-width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
</style>
```

Comment: sorry, I deleted v-b-tooltip code from the b-table because it shows up nothing

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for the inconvenience, it turns out I put the v-b-tooltip inside the <b-table> tag, it should be between <b-table> and </b-table> so now the hover is solved. All that left is pagination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is pretty self-explanatory: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/pagination
But I added several comments on the code below (the template is therefore invalid!)

```html
<template>
  <div class="overflow-auto">
    <b-pagination
      v-model="currentPage" // this is the most important, bind the currentPage state to the pagination component, two-way data binding
      :total-rows="rows" // display how much total data there is
      :per-page="perPage" // this one will tell how much data per page you want to display
      aria-controls="my-table" // this is for a11y
    ></b-pagination>

    <p class="mt-3">Current Page: {{ currentPage }}</p>

    <b-table
      id="my-table"
      :items="items" // where to look for the data
      :per-page="perPage"
      :current-page="currentPage" // re-use the current value of the pagination component
      small
    ></b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        perPage: 3,
        currentPage: 1,
        items: [ // your items, that you may replace with a new array if fetching an API in between each pagination page change
          { id: 1, first_name: 'Fred', last_name: 'Flintstone' },
          { id: 2, first_name: 'Wilma', last_name: 'Flintstone' },
          { id: 3, first_name: 'Barney', last_name: 'Rubble' },
          { id: 4, first_name: 'Betty', last_name: 'Rubble' },
          { id: 5, first_name: 'Pebbles', last_name: 'Flintstone' },
          { id: 6, first_name: 'Bamm Bamm', last_name: 'Rubble' },
          { id: 7, first_name: 'The Great', last_name: 'Gazzoo' },
          { id: 8, first_name: 'Rockhead', last_name: 'Slate' },
          { id: 9, first_name: 'Pearl', last_name: 'Slaghoople' }
        ]
      }
    },
    computed: {
      rows() {
        return this.items.length
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Of course, depending of the amount of data, you may want to watch for the `currentPage` value and make a new API call, fetching the next elements.
This totally depends on the API implementation but it's essentially passing `2` rather than `1` in URL's query params or somewhere into the headers.

As you can see in Github's API here: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-repositories-for-the-authenticated-user--parameters
Theirs is awaiting for a `page` and `per_page` params, hence the values of our VueJS state that we will send a new API call with.